# clique, independent set, and minimum vertex cover

Tags: graphs

I was given a graph problem with 3 different questions and 1 set of answers. The problem is described below. The problem that I'm having is that it seems to me that the answer to all the questions is the same. I keep trying to find a caveat but I don't see one. What am I missing?

Here is the problem

Undirected graph $G$. $n$ - number of vertices. $m$ - number of edges. $d$ - maximum degree of a graph.

1. The maximum clique size of $G$ is no larger than
2. The minimum vertex cover size of $G$ is no larger than
3. The maximum independent set size of $\overline{G}$, the complement of $G$, is no larger than

Set of answers

- (a) $d+1$
- (b) $n$
- (c) $n-1$
- (d) $n/2$
- (e) $d$
- (f) $n-d$

It looks to me that the answer to every problem is (b) $n$, because

1. Clique cannot have more vertices than there are in a graph
2. Vertex cover cannot be larger than the number of vertices in a graph
3. Maximum independent set cannot be larger than the number of vertices in a graph.

I feel like I'm missing something, because the answers seem too obvious.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Of course, $n$ being the largest of the given answers will satisfy all conditions. You are expected to find the least upper bounds though.

Comment: This is where I'm stuck then. How would I even start reasoning about this problem?

Comment: First, You know that there exist graphs, for which $n$ is the exact solution, so you have to think about $d$. Think of some graphs that can't have a cover of $n$. What do they have in common?

Comment: I'm at a loss. What could the graphs that don't have a cover of $n$ have in common? The only thing I can think of is that total degree of a graph is equal the double count of edges, i.e. $d=2m$

Comment: What I was aiming for was **an edge**.

Comment: I feel really stupid, because I still don't see it. What do edges give me, how are they related to the set of answers that has been given go me?

Comment: The only graph that has the minimum vertex cover of $n$ is the graph with no edges. If you have one edge, then it's $n-1$. Having one or more edges also means having a vertex with positive degree. What if $d=5$? What's the minimum cover then?

Comment: It can't possibly be $n-d$, at least I don't think (Example could be if $n=4$ and all the vertices are connected by a single line. $d$ would be equal to $6$. So it can't be $n-d$) The only reasonable answer I can think of is n/2. 


Am I correct in my understanding that for a graph with no edges vertex cover doesn't exist since there are no edges to cover.

Comment: Would you mind helping me to reason about the other two problems as well?

Comment: [Check your definition of degree.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(graph_theory))

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(graph_theory)): the degree (or valency) of a vertex of a graph is the number of edges incident to the vertex, with loops counted twice. What am I missing?

Comment: So from a [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(graph_theory)) definition, I can say that if we have a graph with 2 vertices connected by an edge, total degree of a graph is 2.

Comment: I had a wrong definition of a maximum degree of a graph. For some strange reason I thought it was the total degree. I think I got it. Thanks for the help.